# How can I send sms using codeigniter 4?

Tags: sms, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to send SMS using CodeIgniter 4 but something went wrong any help or another way to send?
This is my code:

```
public function message()
    {
        /*Check submit button */
        if ($this->request->getPost()) {
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $data=$this->users_model->getUserByEmail($email);
            $phone=$data['phone'];
            $authKey = "3456655757gEr5a019b18";
            /*Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma*/
            $mobileNumber = $phone;
            /*Sender ID,While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.*/
            $senderId = "ABCDEF";
            /*Your message to send, Add URL encoding here.*/
            $message = "From Codeigniter 4";
            /*Define route */
            $route = "route=4";
            /*Prepare you post parameters*/
            $postData = array(
                'authkey' => $authKey,
                'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
                'message' => $message,
                'sender' => $senderId,
                'route' => $route
            );
            /*API URL*/
            $url="https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php";
            /* init the resource */
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
                /*,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true*/
            ));
            /*Ignore SSL certificate verification*/
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            /*get response*/
            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            /*Print error if any*/
            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            echo "Message Sent Successfully !";
            
       }
    }
```

After run the code above my web page return "Message Sent Successfully!", but nothing received in my phone. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What does the cURL call responds in the `$output` variable?

You already put the output in it and i think it will guide you to the reason why the SMS is not sending out to your phone.